# Is any method which allows segmentation of long diagonalizing procedures?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, diagonalization

This is a question for a smarter way of numerical computation.

When I diagonalize a certain type of Vandermonde-matrices in Pari/GP ("mateigen(M)"), for instance of size 16x16 then this can be done in say a couple seconds and internal float precision of, say 200 digits (my default, it might be possible with less). If I want to use size 32x32 I need then say 800 or even 1200 digits internal float precision. The size 64x64 is currently my favorite extent; but it needs more than 3000 digits (I use 4000 to avoid error-abortions) and last time I've tried, was 6000 secs. Also - if something is going wrong, say too few internal digits or insufficient memory, then it may happen, that Pari/GP calculates 1 hour - but then detects some error ("insufficient eigen sapce" - means I need more precision) - and everything done is lost....

So I'd like to try other methods which might allow step-wise improvement in some fashion - partial computation with submatrices, increasing accuracy or the like. For instance I do not yet see a possibility to take advantage of the procedure to compute the roots of the characteristic polynomial in advance - there is no procedure to compute the eigenvectors which exploits the knowledge of the eigenvalues. So my question (in general, not dependend on Pari/GP- I might program this myself):

Q: Is there some procedure to split the diagonalization into more distinct steps whose results solve the problem cumulatively?

Comment: Suppose that, instead of aborting, the method paused due to insufficient precision, and you could at-will increase your precision to 5000 or more. Would your results for the first $N$ steps even be valid?

Comment: @Arkamis: thanks for your input! Hmm, I've considered (and even implemented) a couple of possible methods but it's difficult to say whether they finally converge (if they are iterative) to the best approximate solution... Let's consider Newton-iteration for interpolation: you can begin with bad precision and can improve precision when you are already near the true solution. Maybe there's something here too - with matrices there are sometimes extreme clever methods (only think of matrix-multiplication with order less than O(n^2)!)

Comment: I would imagine that it's probably not hard to memoize the algorithm, but I'd worry about the residual buildup. I'm trying to think of whether or not I've ever come across memoization in iterative matrix methods. I can't say I have, but I also can't say I know of a good reason not to...

Comment: @Arkamis: Well, the Newton-iteration to find the square-root of a matrix(if it exists) is an example. Also the "Hotelling"-Method to find the eigenvector for the highest eigenvalue of a correlation-matrix( which is symmetric) comes to mind: here you begin simpy with the unit-vector and proceed iteratively to approach the best possible approximation. Also here we can improve the internal precision after ("provisorical") convergence was achieved with lower precison.